# Using reflection to update embedded resource in an assembly?

Tags: c#

I have an exe file that has embedded resource inside. I'd need to write another application that would open the exe, update it's resource and save it back as a valid executable. (I can't recompile it because machine where it'll be run may not have it's source available).

Is that possible and how (I need an idea or possibly a link, not asking for a full solution)?

Edit: Assembly I need to update is a .NET 3.5 assembly.

Comment: Wouldn't you like to store resources somewhere else then? This sound like bad idea even if you find a way.

Comment: Are your refering to "native ressources" or .NET ressources? IIRC they are different. For the first one there is [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm) which comes with source code.

Comment: When I make updates, I just replace the entire executable with the new version. Why do you need to go the long winded route of modifying it and recompiling it?

Comment: @Ales, yes, I'd prefer keeping it separate (then I wouldn't have problems at all) but the management insists on it being an embedded resource...

Comment: @Amicable The machine where it'll be running may not have the source or the original assembly (or any development tool for that matter) so they can't recompile it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can add a new class in the assembly with embedded resources that will manipulate those resources. And then call manipulating methods using reflection. I mean something like this:

```
/*The program which has embedded resources*/
public static class ResourceManager
{
     public static void ChangeResource1(Base64 newResource);
     /*** Other methods***/
}

/*The program that modifies resources*/
MethodInfo[] method = typeof(ResourceManager).GetMethod(ChangeResource1);
method.Invoke(someNewData);
```

Not sure if it will work though...